# Simple binary heap in C#

Tags: c#, heap

I've written a simple binary heap in C# and I want to know if it has any problems or if I can make it better.

```
public enum HeapType
{
    MinHeap,
    MaxHeap
}

public class Heap<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    List<T> items;

    public HeapType MinOrMax { get; private set; }

    public T Root
    {
        get { return items[0]; }
    }

    public Heap(HeapType type)
    {
        items = new List<T>();
        this.MinOrMax = type;
    }

    public void Insert(T item)
    {
        items.Add(item);

        int i = items.Count - 1;

        bool flag = true;
        if (MinOrMax == HeapType.MaxHeap)
            flag = false;

        while(i > 0)
        {
            if ((items[i].CompareTo(items[(i - 1) / 2]) > 0) ^ flag)
            {
                T temp = items[i];
                items[i] = items[(i - 1) / 2];
                items[(i - 1) / 2] = temp;
                i = (i - 1) / 2;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    public void DeleteRoot()
    {
        int i = items.Count - 1;

        items[0] = items[i];
        items.RemoveAt(i);

        i = 0;

        bool flag = true;
        if (MinOrMax == HeapType.MaxHeap)
            flag = false;

        while(true)
        {
            int leftInd = 2 * i + 1;
            int rightInd = 2 * i + 2;
            int largest = i;

            if (leftInd < items.Count)
            {
                if ((items[leftInd].CompareTo(items[largest]) > 0) ^ flag)
                    largest = leftInd;
            }

            if (rightInd < items.Count)
            {
                if ((items[rightInd].CompareTo(items[largest]) > 0) ^ flag)
                    largest = rightInd;
            }

            if (largest != i)
            {
                T temp = items[largest];
                items[largest] = items[i];
                items[i] = temp;
                i = largest;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    public T PopRoot()
    {
        T result = items[0];

        DeleteRoot();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You accepted an answer after only an hour? That's your prerogative I guess, but usually on codereview.se people wait 24 hours to get a bunch of replies, then pick the most helpful or insightful one. Accepting an answer early might discourage other people from posting.

Comment: @Snowbody you are right. well this is my first post on codereview. I'm a noob lolz

Comment: A related post [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/68530/117705) implementing minHeap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> public HeapType MinOrMax { get; private set; }
> ```

I'm wary of any name that has the words `And` or `Or` in it. It often indicates that something has too many responsibilities. Names like `HeapType` inside of a `Heap` class are also indicative that you should be considering some inheritance and an OOP approach.

I'm not saying for sure that it's better, but you may want to consider using an abstract base class that both `MinHeap` and `MaxHeap` derive their common functionality from.

> ```
> if (MinOrMax == HeapType.MaxHeap)
>     flag = false;
> ```

Use brackets friend. Always use brackets. Better yet, do away with the `if` entirely and assign the result of an expression to your `flag`.

```
flag = !(MinOrMax == HeapType.MaxHeap);
```

You calculate this value several times within several lines of code.

> ```
> (i - 1) / 2
> ```

It would be better to calculate it once and assign the result to a well named variable.

Comment: Just about the HeapType, is just the name bad? Or is the idea of having a class that does two things wrong?

Comment: The idea of having a class that does two things is wrong. The name is just a signal that this is what's happening. (Of course, there are always exceptions to every rule.) Have you heard of the Single Responsibility Principle? It's often referenced when speaking of methods, but the idea applies to classes as well. Like I said, I'm not convinced inheritance is warranted here, but I think it's worth exploring.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was just a bit lazy when I wrote this ;) so I thought a simple xor will do the job. thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Welcome to CR btw.

Comment: My 2 cents: There should be a `Heap` interface; then `MinHeap` and `MaxHeap` implementation classes.

Comment: > Use brackets friend. Always use brackets.
That is wrong. Always use no brackets if you do not have to. Makes code more compact and easier to read. Adding brackets for the lack of small cohesive methods or lack of unit test is bad practice.

Comment: @MartinKersten I’m not going to argue with you, but I have more than objective claims of readability to back up my stance. I present the “goto fail” bug. https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/curly-braces/

Comment: Well this can not happen if you are on auto-format (at least on commit before a review is done) and write the necessary tests. Also if you write small methods (aggressive refactoring), you wont end up with many chances to screw this up. But I acknowledge the argument you are making and its legit. Whenever I can set the code standards, people tend to enjoy to leave out unnecessary curly brackets once they get over the anger of being not allowed to check in overly complex code.

Comment: I’m going to reiterate that I have no interest in arguing about this.

Answer (score 10):

I note that you're restricting your types `T` to those that are `IComparable`, that is, those that implement `CompareTo`. A more general solution would allow the caller to [specify their own `IComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which may be that type's `CompareTo` or may be something else entirely.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336416/using-icomparer-for-sorting

Answer (score 4):

`DeleteRoot()` method should be marked with private access as shown below:

```
private void DeleteRoot()
```

`DeleteRoot()` method is an internal implementation detail of the class which is used by `PopRoot()` method. Outside world consuming the `Heap<T>` class should see only `PopRoot()` method to remove the minimum or maximum element in the heap. It is very confusing that currently there are two ways to delete the root node in your heap binary tree implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe also add a check in PopRoot() to see if there are still items left in the List. Otherwise, popping until the list is empty is not possible without an exception being thrown.

Comment: What would you do in that case other than `throw`ing another exception?

Comment: @Snowbody probably nothing. But the class should provide a Count or Empty property allowing consuming code to handle that just like with all other container classes

Answer (score 1):

You could use delegates here where you have

```
public delegate bool Comparator(T a,T b);
```

This would replace

```
public HeapType MinOrMax { get; private set; }
```

The user would pass in a function that compares the 2 objects and returns a true or false

```
 if (comparator.Invoke(items[i],items[(i - 1) / 2]))
```

this would allow anything about these 2 objects to be tested and then a result to be returned based on this decision. This would make it more fluid, but of course this may be more complicated than needed for some uses.